# Java Streams - Standard Deviation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, standard-deviation

I wish to clarify upfront I am looking for a way to calculate Standard deviation using Streams (I have a working method at present which calculates & returns SD but without using Streams).

The dataset i am working with matches closely as seen in [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340688/group-by-and-sum-objects-like-in-sql-with-java-lambdas/26341146#26341146). As shown in this link am able to group my data & get the average but not able to figure out how to get the SD.

***Code***

```
outPut.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getCar(),
                    Collectors.averagingDouble(e -> (e.getHigh() - e.getLow()))))
            .forEach((car,avgHLDifference) -> System.out.println(car+ "\t" + avgHLDifference));
```

I also checked [Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javaposse/B1t-ViNSXGw) on DoubleSummaryStatistics but it doesn't seem to help for SD.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a custom collector for this task that calculates a sum of square. The buit-in `DoubleSummaryStatistics` collector does not keep track of it. This was discussed by the expert group [in this thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-libs-spec-experts/2013-March/001523.html) but finally not implemented. The difficulty when calculating the sum of squares is the potential overflow when squaring the intermediate results.

```
static class DoubleStatistics extends DoubleSummaryStatistics {

    private double sumOfSquare = 0.0d;
    private double sumOfSquareCompensation; // Low order bits of sum
    private double simpleSumOfSquare; // Used to compute right sum for non-finite inputs

    @Override
    public void accept(double value) {
        super.accept(value);
        double squareValue = value * value;
        simpleSumOfSquare += squareValue;
        sumOfSquareWithCompensation(squareValue);
    }

    public DoubleStatistics combine(DoubleStatistics other) {
        super.combine(other);
        simpleSumOfSquare += other.simpleSumOfSquare;
        sumOfSquareWithCompensation(other.sumOfSquare);
        sumOfSquareWithCompensation(other.sumOfSquareCompensation);
        return this;
    }

    private void sumOfSquareWithCompensation(double value) {
        double tmp = value - sumOfSquareCompensation;
        double velvel = sumOfSquare + tmp; // Little wolf of rounding error
        sumOfSquareCompensation = (velvel - sumOfSquare) - tmp;
        sumOfSquare = velvel;
    }

    public double getSumOfSquare() {
        double tmp =  sumOfSquare + sumOfSquareCompensation;
        if (Double.isNaN(tmp) && Double.isInfinite(simpleSumOfSquare)) {
            return simpleSumOfSquare;
        }
        return tmp;
    }

    public final double getStandardDeviation() {
        return getCount() > 0 ? Math.sqrt((getSumOfSquare() / getCount()) - Math.pow(getAverage(), 2)) : 0.0d;
    }

}
```

Then, you can use this class with

```
Map<String, Double> standardDeviationMap =
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            e -> e.getCar(),
            Collectors.mapping(
                e -> e.getHigh() - e.getLow(),
                Collector.of(
                    DoubleStatistics::new,
                    DoubleStatistics::accept,
                    DoubleStatistics::combine,
                    d -> d.getStandardDeviation()
                )
            )
        ));
```

This will collect the input list into a map where the values corresponds to the standard deviation of `high - low` for the same key.

Comment: thank you very much. I am able to get the SD. I am now checking to see if I can Collect both averagingDouble & SD (like - car, averageHL, SD) in the same stream() call instead of 2 streams.

Comment: @iCoder The `DoubleStatistics` in this answer collect SD and the average yes. You could have a `Map<String, DoubleStatistics>` with all the info.

Comment: The interesting fact regarding overflow: nobody cares that `LongSummaryStatistics` actually overflows the sum, so `LongStream.of(Long.MAX_VALUE, Long.MAX_VALUE).summaryStatistics().getAverage()` is `-1.0`. Chances to hit this overflow, to my opinion are higher than chances to hit sum-of-squares overflow...

Comment: @Tunaki not quite sure what mistake I am doing but the moment I change Map<String, Double> to Map<String, DoubleStatistics>  I am getting a error message cannot resolve getScrip() in the groupingBy. I guess am making some elementary mistake, need to ponder more I suppose.

Comment: In Java 1.8.0_92, the example use throws the error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<String,Double>

Comment: they could also just have used bigdecimal. I really do not understand why java is not learning from scala, python and R ... the whole collections implementation lacks of so many things ....

Comment: This answer could as well just compute the square of standard deviation incrementally without overflowing anything. `stddev = (stddev * prevcount + newsquare) / count` not sure why this method wasn't accepted by the expert group.

Comment: What if I just want to return the std of a list of numbers? Specifying `.collect(Collector.of(...)...)` does not work ("the method collect is not applicable for the arguments..")

Answer (score 5):

You can use this custom Collector :

```
private static final Collector<Double, double[], Double> VARIANCE_COLLECTOR = Collector.of( // See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance
        () -> new double[3], // {count, mean, M2}
        (acu, d) -> { // See chapter about Welford's online algorithm and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/198336/how-to-calculate-standard-deviation-with-streaming-inputs
            acu[0]++; // Count
            double delta = d - acu[1];
            acu[1] += delta / acu[0]; // Mean
            acu[2] += delta * (d - acu[1]); // M2
        },
        (acuA, acuB) -> { // See chapter about "Parallel algorithm" : only called if stream is parallel ...
            double delta = acuB[1] - acuA[1];
            double count = acuA[0] + acuB[0];
            acuA[2] = acuA[2] + acuB[2] + delta * delta * acuA[0] * acuB[0] / count; // M2
            acuA[1] += delta * acuB[0] / count;  // Mean
            acuA[0] = count; // Count
            return acuA;
        },
        acu -> acu[2] / (acu[0] - 1.0), // Var = M2 / (count - 1)
        UNORDERED);
```

Then simply call this collector on your stream :

```
double stdDev = Math.sqrt(outPut.stream().boxed().collect(VARIANCE_COLLECTOR));
```