# Computing sum and sum-of-squares at the same time with Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I was wondering if there is any way to achieve the following within a single iteration over the array. Simply to have two different results out of stream.

```
double sum = Arrays.stream(doubles).sum();
double sumOfSquares = Arrays.stream(doubles).map(d -> d * d).sum();
```

Comment: If you find yourself need lots of these kinds of statistics then subclassing [DoubleSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) might make sense.

Comment: Related question (using the idea from @the8472) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36263352/java-streams-standard-deviation

Comment: The recommended approach here is indeed to subclass `DoubleSummaryStatistics`.  That said, be careful.  We considered including sum-of-squares in DSS, but chose not to because (a) its more computation that many users want, but more importantly (b) it is very easy to get in numerical trouble with floating point calculating variance by sum-of-squares.  (Squaring makes big numbers bigger and small numbers smaller, leading to risk of losing data when you add them.)  See Knuth AOCP, vol 2, sec 4.2.2 for more details.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you could with a custom collector, for instance:

```
double[] res =
    Arrays.stream(doubles)
          .collect(() -> new double[2],
                   (arr, e) -> {arr[0]+=e; arr[1]+=e*e;},
                   (arr1, arr2) -> {arr1[0]+=arr2[0]; arr1[1]+=arr2[1];});

double sum = res[0];
double sumOfSquares = res[1];
```

but you don't gain much readability in my opinion, so I would stick with the multiple passes solution (or maybe just use a for-loop in this case).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still learning streams, so it's really helpful.

Comment: Well, as far as I'm concerned, streams don't generally result in increased readability, especially where some more than basic operation is needed (as is the case here). I can't help but smile when stream proponents claim that for loops are less readable, they are by far the most intuitive, breaking down the logic in the most obvious way. That said, this solution really helps when one wants to do a parallel Monte Carlo simulation and wants the standard error too. The way I understand it the alternative would be to use thread pools, futures, etc and that's definitely less readable and concise?