# Aggregate data in hashmap based on date

Tags: java, angular, spring, jpa

My Spring boot back end manage apps and games.
I have Rating Object and in this rating object and save rating history in an HashMap

```
// Number of history by day
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Map<String, Integer> ratingHistory = new HashMap<>();
```

I will have something like :

```
"ratingHistory": {
  "07/01/2020": 12,
  "07/02/2020": 5,
  "07/03/2020": 0
}
```

This json will grow...

I want to display a chart showing the evolution of the rating for:
this week :  I will return the 7 last data in my hashmap
[image]

How could I aggregate and return processed data when I want to display:

- last 30 days rating evolution (I want to show week 1 (sum of all days of this week), week 2, week3, week 4)
- last 3 months (May(sum of all days of this month), June, July)
- from the beginning of the app...

I have no idea about how to correctly handle it.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Java 8+, you should change the `Map<String, Integer>` to a [`NavigableMap<LocalDate, Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html), which in reality will be a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

This ensures that the keys are sortable, allowing you to call [`subMap(LocalDate from, LocalDate to)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#subMap-K-K-), which will help once the map grows very large.

Also, the use of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) makes it easier to group by:

- Week: `WeekFields.of(Locale.US)`, and the 2 methods [`weekBasedYear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekBasedYear--) and [`weekOfWeekBasedYear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekOfWeekBasedYear--).
- Month: [`YearMonth.from(LocalDate date)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#from-java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor-)

As for how to do the actual aggregation using Java 8+ Streams, there are lots of examples of that on the web, using `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(...))`, e.g. [Group by and sum objects like in SQL with Java lambdas?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26346574/5221149).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use java 8, I will change for localDate and try it again