# JAVA List GroupBy multiple fields and Sum

Tags: java

I have list having fields  Name, Currency and Amount.
I want to group it by Name,  Currency and Sum of Amount.

[image: This is sample data and output]

```
List<myPojo> rows= ................

public class myPojo
{

    private String name;
    private String currency;
    private BigDecimal amount;

......................
}
```

I want result/output in list

Comment: To me it seems to be just sorted, first by Name, then by whatever. I don't see any grouping in the output. Anyway, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Amongalen I want groupby with SUM of amount

Comment: @Amongalen they are grouped, by name *and* currency.

Comment: @ShivprsadSammbhare the question stands: what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Possibly related: [Group by multiple field names in java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28342814), [Group by and sum objects like in SQL with Java lambdas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26340688)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Stream API.
Use `Collectors.toMap` and use `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` as key of map. Then define merge function for multiple values of the same key.

```
List<myPojo> res = new ArrayList<>(rows.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getName(), e.getCurrency()),
                        Function.identity(),
                        (a, b) -> new myPojo(a.getName(), a.getCurrency(), a.getAmount().add(b.getAmount()))))
                .values());
```

Demo:

```
List<myPojo> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new myPojo("A", "USD", new BigDecimal(1.0)));
list.add(new myPojo("A", "USD", new BigDecimal(2.0)));
list.add(new myPojo("A", "USD", new BigDecimal(3.0)));
list.add(new myPojo("B", "USD", new BigDecimal(1.0)));
list.add(new myPojo("B", "USD", new BigDecimal(2.0)));
list.add(new myPojo("B", "USD", new BigDecimal(3.0)));
list.add(new myPojo("A", "US", new BigDecimal(1.0)));
list.add(new myPojo("A", "US", new BigDecimal(2.0)));
list.add(new myPojo("A", "US", new BigDecimal(3.0)));
List<myPojo> res = new ArrayList<>(list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getName(), e.getCurrency()),
                    Function.identity(),
                    (a, b) -> new myPojo(a.getName(), a.getCurrency(), a.getAmount().add(b.getAmount()))))
            .values());
System.out.println(res.toString());
```

Output:

```
[myPojo [name=B, currency=USD, amount=6], 
 myPojo [name=A, currency=USD, amount=6], 
 myPojo [name=A, currency=US, amount=6]]
```

*Note:* Try to capitalize the name of the class like `MyPojo` for better convention

Comment: What if myPojo don't have constructor. Then how to get these values

Comment: Create a constructor then, without constructor how you set values ? Without constructor, you need to set each value using setter. like `(a,b) -> {myPojo p = new myPojo(); p.setName(a.getName());..... return p;`

Comment: Another way is `(a, b) -> { a.setAmount(a.getAmount().add(b.getAmount()));
           return a;}))` but it will mulate your current list

Comment: @ShivprsadSammbhare Is your problem solved? feel free to ask for help

Answer (score 1):

You could use groupingBy to generate a `Map<String,Map<String,BigDecimal>>` corresponding to `Map<Name,Map<Currency,sum of Amount>>`

```
List<myPojo> rows = List.of(new myPojo("ABCD", "USD", new BigDecimal(20)),
                            new myPojo("XYZ",  "GBP", new BigDecimal(60)),
                            new myPojo("XYZ",  "THB", new BigDecimal(35)),
                            new myPojo("ABCD", "INR", new BigDecimal(90)),
                            new myPojo("ABCD", "USD", new BigDecimal(80)),
                            new myPojo("XYZ",  "THB", new BigDecimal(45)));
    
Map<String,Map<String,BigDecimal>> map = 
            rows.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(myPojo::getName,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(myPojo::getCurrency,
                            Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, myPojo::getAmount, BigDecimal::add))));
    System.out.println(map);

 // output: {XYZ={GBP=60, THB=80}, ABCD={USD=100, INR=90}}
```