# Compare elements within arraylist of Object using java stream

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

I have list of Object . I want to compare elements of the list and perform operation if the are equal on a condition.

`class A{ String abc; int pqr; }`

I have List items with me
`"items": [ { "pqr": 2, "abc": 1994 }, { "pqr": 2, "abc": 1994 }, { "pqr": 1, "abc": 64 } ]`

Now i want my output list as
`"items": [ { "pqr": 4, "abc": 1994 }, { "pqr": 1, "abc": 64 } ]`
i/e comparing th elements on the basis of abc and if its is same add its pqr value and remove the duplicate.

How can i do this using stream or efficiently?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26340688/group-by-and-sum-objects-like-in-sql-with-java-lambdas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Ralf you can use `groupingBy` to get a `Map` with `abc` as key and the sum of `pqr` as value:

```
Map<String, Integer> groupBy = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Container::getAbc, Collectors.summingInt(Container::getPqr)));
System.out.println(groupBy);
```

produces `{1994=4, 64=1}`.
If you need to convert this to a `List` you have to iterate over this `map`:

```
List<Container> list = groupBy.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new Container(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

produces (with overwritten `toString`) `[A{abc=1994, pqr=4}, A{abc=64, pqr=1}]`